# Struggling To Get Outer Join To Work

Tags: sql, oracle, outer-join

Wondering if anyone can help.

I have the following tables

Depatments

(
DeptID

DeptType

DeptName
)
.

.

.

.

.

DepartmentChars

(
DeptID

CharType

CharVal

EffDate
)

.

.

.

DeptID is the Primary Key on both tables, and whilst the examples I have generally seen would indicate this should all reside on the 1 table, it is the schema I working with.

.
.
.
.

The results I want back are the following.

Deptartments.DeptID, Department.DeptName with DepartmentChars.CharType, DepartmentChars.CharVal, DepartmentChars.EffDate

with the following criteria

I want the CharType to be one specific value (IE Watercooler)

Following on from this If there is a value for this CharType in the Department, I want the last entry only (MAX EffDate)

However, if there isnt a value for this Char Type, then I want the DeptID and DeptName listed, followed by 3 nulls for the values on the DepartmentChars table.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: To get faster results,please look here on how to ask :https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: You basically need a `SELECT` query where you are selecting from `Departments d LEFT OUTER JOIN DepartmentChars c ON (d.DeptID = c.DeptID)` instead of selecting from a single table. You can then use `GROUP BY` and anything else you might wish, just as though you were selecting from a single table.

Comment: Hi Mike,I have tried this, but for some reason, if there are no results on the Char Type table, then no rows are returned as oppose to 1 row being returned for the Department, with null values for the Char Type. Is there something simple that I am missing?

Comment: Please show your DDL, query, input & output & expected output for an example. Read & act on [mcve]. PS Write a select to return ids & max dates, then join that with Departments.